# R - Passing assignment operator "<" as string in SOAP call

Tags: r, curl, soap, operators, variable-assignment

I have a web service that accepts R code as string, executes it, serialize the results and sends it back as string which is then unserialized and displayed in R console. Based on some logic R code is built dynamically as string. The String R code is sent to the web service using curl. Body of the curl will have  the string R code as one parameter. 
When there is an assignment operator "<" in the Curl Body, web service never receives the parameter value.
When I print the Curl body I see the R code constructed correctly. I found that the issue with the assignment operator in the body.

E.g. summary(iris) works well

this code fails

```
x<- summary(iris)
x
```

Anyone know how to overcome this issue?

here is the sudo code

```
strrcode <- "x<-summary(iris) \n x"
body  <- paste('<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?>
         <soap:Envelope xmlns="urn:xxx:xx:xxxx" xmlns:SOAP-
ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <soap:Body>
         <Info>
         <id>', ID  , '</Wuid>
<Cluster>', targetCluster , '</Cluster>
<Rcode>', strrcode , '</Rcode>
         </Info>
         </soap:Body>
         </soap:Envelope>', sep="")
```

Comment: You could just use `=` for assignment.

Comment: Could you edit your example to include values for `strrcode` that work and that don't work?

Comment: Thank You Gregor. I added the code that doesn't work. Will try = and let you know the results.

Comment: Probably you need to escape the backslash. Use `\\n` instead of `\n`. Another option would be to use a semilcolon `;` instead of the line break.

Comment: "=" for assignment worked. No issues with \n. Thank you Gregor